# Dynamic Sql Query Not Executed?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below dynamic query:

```
SET @DynamicPIVOT = 'SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT StudentId, IsForeNoon,Date as date1 FROM Attendance_FN_AN
) as  Books
PIVOT (
    Count(IsForeNoon) FOR date1 IN (' + @cols + ')
    ) as  Result'
END

exec @DynamicPIVOT;
```

When I execute the above dynamic query, single quotation not removed from the front and last so that The Issue come for

```
The name 'SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT StudentId, IsForeNoon,Date as date1 FROM Attendance_FN_AN
) as  Books
PIVOT (
    Count(IsForeNoon) FOR date1 IN ([2015-04-16])
    ) as  Result' is not a valid identifier.
```

Any solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `exec @DynamicPIVOT;` use `exec(@DynamicPIVOT)`.

Better to use [SP_EXECUTESQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx). The big thing about SP_EXECUTESQL is that it allows you to create parameterized queries which is very good if you care about SQL injection.